# Is there a way to program the EV3 brick with NXC?

Tags: software, ev3, nxc

I tried to program the EV3 brick with NXC so i used BricxCC. The download of the program to the EV3 was successful but when i tried to start the program (which actually didn't show up on the program screen), there was a "FILE NAME ERROR". I use the Firmware V1.03H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not right now. RobotC support is already there ( although it isn't free ).